# Prove that $ \int_\Omega F^2\leq\int_\Omega\big(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\big)^2$.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $\Omega=\{(x,\,y)\;\big|\;0\leq x\leq1,\,\phi(x)\leq y\leq\psi(x)\}$, $F(x,\,\phi(x))=0$ and $F$ has continuous partial derivatives. Prove that 
>   $$
> \int_\Omega F^2\leq\int_\Omega\big(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\big)^2.
> $$

To gain some intuition, I set $F(x,\,y)=xy$ and find that the inequality holds, but I don't know the general case, or even can't start.

Answer (score 1):

This is some kind of Poincare inequality.

First, we have
$$
\int_0^1 \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} F(x,y)^2 dydx
=\int_0^1 \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} \left( \int_{\phi(x)}^y F_y(x,t)dt\right)^2 dydx.
$$
By H\"older inequality
$$
\int_{\phi(x)}^y F_y(x,t)\cdot 1\ dt \le \left( \int_{\phi(x)}^y F_y(x,t)^2 dt \right)^{1/2}  (  \left(\int_{\phi(x)}^y 1^2 dt \right)^{1/2} \\
\le \left( \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} F_y(x,t)^2 dt \right)^{1/2} \sqrt{ \psi(x)-\phi(x)}.
$$
Using this in the first equation
$$
\int_0^1 \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} F(x,y)^2 dydx
\le \int_0^1 \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} F_y(x,t)^2 dt 
(\psi(x)-\phi(x)) dydx\\
=  \int_0^1  \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} F_y(x,t)^2 dt 
(\psi(x)-\phi(x)) dx\\
\le \max_{x\in[0,1]}(\psi(x)-\phi(x))\int_0^1  \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} F_y(x,t)^2 dt dx.
$$
If $\psi(x)-\phi(x)\le 1$ for all $x$, then the desired inequality follows.